# how to remove elements without a specified class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got a big HTML page. Some elements (can be p, h1, div etc.) are tagged with the class 'keep_me'.
I need to remove all the elements present in the page WITHOUT this class? Any idea on how to do it with jQuery?

I tried with something like that, but it doesn't work (obviously ;) :

```
jQuery('#content *').remove(":not('[class=keep_me]')");
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just do:

```
jQuery('#content :not(.keep_me)').remove();
```

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

> *jQuery(':not(selector)')*
>
> Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.

Comment: cheers, there was no example with a class so I deduced it was not working that way!

Comment: @vincentp: You can use anything that is a valid selector.

Answer (score 5):

Use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

> The .not() method is typically faster and may end up providing you
>   with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or
>   variables into a :not() selector filter.

```
$('#content *').not('.keep_me').remove();
```